# Ensuring I have a closed point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, Exercise II.3.20, reads (in part):

> Let $X$ be an integral scheme of finite type over a field $k$.
>
> (a) *[Prove:]* For any closed point $P \in X$, $\dim X = \dim \mathcal{O}_P$, where for rings we always mean the Krull dimension.
>
> *[...]*

I'm stuck on a point which is completely tangential to the actual business about dimension.  Here's my proof:

> Let $\emptyset \neq X_0 \subset X_1 \subset \cdots \subset X_n \subseteq X$ be an increasing chain of irreducible closed subsets of $X$ of maximum length, so that $n = \dim X$.  (In fact $X_n = X$ since $X$ is irreducible.)  Let $U \subseteq X$ be an open affine subset which meets $X_0$, and write $A := \mathcal{O}_X(U)$. As $X$ is of finite type over $k$, $A$ is a finitely-generated $k$-algebra by Exercise II.3.3(b).
>
> It follows from general topology that $\dim U = \dim X$.  *[etc.]*
>
> We've now done enough to reduce the problem to the affine case.  To see this, consider a closed point $P \in X$.  $P$ is contained in some open affine set $V$, which intersects $U$ since $X$ is irreducible.  **Let $Q$ be a closed point in $U \cap V$.**  Assuming the affine case, we have
>   $$\dim \mathcal{O}_{X, P} = \dim V = \dim \mathcal{O}_{X, Q} = \dim U = \dim X$$
>   which establishes the desired result.
>
> So suppose that $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ for some finitely-generated $k$-algebra $A$. *[etc.]*

I'm concerned with the bolded sentence, "Let $Q$ be a closed point of $U \cap V$."  In particular, how do I ensure that $U \cap V$ contains a closed point?  As I understand it, the hypothesis that $X$ is integral of finite type over a field is vital here -- if I take two arbitrary open affines and glue them together then I can easily create a situation where $U \cap V$ doesn't contain a closed point.

However, I'm having trouble seeing how to get anything out of this hypothesis.  For instance, $U \cap V$ isn't necessarily affine, and though it contains some affine set a point could be closed in that affine but not in $U \cap V$.

Am I just being stupid here?  How do you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are completely on the right track. $U \cap V$ contains an affine $W$, and $W$ will have a closed point $x$ (closed in $W$). But since $X$ is of finite type over a field, $x$ is in fact closed in $X$ (and hence in particular closed in $U \cap V$) as well. This is an immediate consequence of the following result.

> Let $X$ be a scheme, which is locally of finite type over a field $k$. A point $x \in X$ is closed, if and only if the residue field $\kappa(x)$ is a finite algebraic extension of $k$.

Cf. for example Görtz-Wedhorn, Proposition 3.33. Indeed, using this result one can even show that on any scheme $X$ as above the set of closed points is dense in $X$.